# Como renderizar html passando como string do controller para a view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tenho a seguinte view:

```
    public ActionResult RelatorioEquipe()
    {
        ViewRelatorioEquipeDTO dto = new ViewRelatorioEquipeDTO();
        dto.LstUnidadeGerencial = negocio.Relatorio.ObterLstUg();
        dto.LstExercicios = new ExercicioNegocio().ObterExerciciosAtivos();

        dto.Html = "<img src=\"~/Imagens/LogoMetroRelatorio.png\" style=\"float: left\" />";        

        return View(dto);
    }
```

`dto.Html` é uma string e quando eu referencio na minha pagina (cshtml):

```
<div class="logo">
    @Model.Html
</div>
```

A página naturalmente mostra uma string com esse texto.

A questão é: tem como ao invés de mostrar a string, renderizar esse html e mostrar a imagem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei o que eu procurava. Consegui renderizar o html no razor fazendo apenas isso:

```
<div class="logo">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Html)
</div>
```

Comment: Só pra eu entender: qual a necessidade de você montar HTML no seu Controller?

Comment: É porque meu gerador de PDF só gera o PDF através da renderização da view. Na minha view normal tenho um método que entrega JSON pra página via ajax e atualiza, mas ai o PDF não consegue gerar essa atualização. Repliquei o método e mandei retornar html para uma view nova para poder gerar o pdf.

Answer (score 2):

Sim.

Implemente no seu projeto a seguinte extensão:

```
public static class ImageHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src, string altText, string height, string style = "")
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", src);
        builder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
        builder.MergeAttribute("height", height);
        if (style != "") builder.MergeAttribute("style", style);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string url, string altText, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.Attributes.Add("src", url);
        builder.Attributes.Add("alt", altText);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
@Html.Image("caminho/da/imagem", "texto alternativo", "altura", "float: left")
```

Ou então:

```
@Html.Image("caminho/da/imagem", "texto alternativo", new { style = "float: left", border = "0" })
```

Não esqueça do `using` na `View`:

```
@using SeuProjeto.Extensions
```

`Extensions` é um exemplo, mas você pode colocar a classe estática em qualquer lugar.