# Inserir texto identado no TextArea com CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo um editor `HTML` no browser, onde o usuário pode gravar seu script no Banco de Dados, eu gravei todas as linhas de código do usuário em uma única string e gravei no BD, mas como faço para trazer novamente como usuário criou?

Atualmente está assim:

[image: Atualmente está assim]

Alguém sabe se o CodeMirror tem alguma função que reajuste isso, ou outra idéia ?!

Comment: respondi sua pergunta. Caso acrescente mais detalhes, posso melhora-la.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como renderizar html passando como string do controller para a view?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19208/como-renderizar-html-passando-como-string-do-controller-para-a-view)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um `HtmlHelper` que Suporta a renderização de controles `HTML` em uma exibição. Em sua `View` utilize-o assim:

```
 @Html.Raw(Model.StringDoBanco)
```